# onSaveInstanceState crashes my app

Tags: android, crash, lifecycle

why does my app crash, when I leave my activity? To be more specific: Everything worked fine until I implemented `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`

Here is the code:

```
 @Override
 protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState){


        outState.putString("d1",(((EditText) findViewById (R.id.request_detail1)).getText()).toString());
        outState.putString("d2",(((EditText) findViewById (R.id.request_detail2)).getText()).toString());
        outState.putString("d3",(((EditText) findViewById (R.id.request_detail3)).getText()).toString());
        outState.putString("d4",(((EditText) findViewById (R.id.request_detail4)).getText()).toString());
        outState.putString("inputNr", (((EditText) findViewById (R.id.poRequest)).getText()).toString());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }



@Override
   protected void onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
             ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.request_detail1)).setText(savedInstanceState.getString("d1"));
             ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.request_detail2)).setText(savedInstanceState.getString("d2"));
             ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.request_detail3)).setText(savedInstanceState.getString("d3"));
             ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.request_detail4)).setText(savedInstanceState.getString("d4"));
             ((EditText) findViewById (R.id.poRequest)).setText(savedInstanceState.getString("inputNr"));

        }
```

LogCat tells me
`08-02 05:23:09.791: E/AndroidRuntime(873):     at net.frontend.androidapp.statusrequest.PurchaseOrderRequest.onSaveInstanceState(PurchaseOrderRequest.java:47)`

the refered line is 
`outState.putString("d1",(((EditText) findViewById (R.id.request_detail1)).getText()).toString());`

I am a little bit confused, as soon as the `onSaveInstanceState()` is called, the app crashes.

and here is the whole code, in case I the error is caused by something else

```
    package net.frontend.androidapp.statusrequest;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PurchaseOrderRequest extends Activity {

private static String preqnr="";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.purchase_order_request_activity);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState){


        outState.putString("d1",(((EditText) findViewById (R.id.request_detail1)).getText()).toString());
        outState.putString("d2",(((EditText) findViewById (R.id.request_detail2)).getText()).toString());
        outState.putString("d3",(((EditText) findViewById (R.id.request_detail3)).getText()).toString());
        outState.putString("d4",(((EditText) findViewById (R.id.request_detail4)).getText()).toString());
        outState.putString("inputNr", (((EditText) findViewById (R.id.poRequest)).getText()).toString());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
         ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.request_detail1)).setText(savedInstanceState.getString("d1"));
         ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.request_detail2)).setText(savedInstanceState.getString("d2"));
         ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.request_detail3)).setText(savedInstanceState.getString("d3"));
         ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.request_detail4)).setText(savedInstanceState.getString("d4"));
         ((EditText) findViewById (R.id.poRequest)).setText(savedInstanceState.getString("inputNr"));

    }
    public void showDetail(View view){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, OrderDetails.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void checkStatus (View view) {

         EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.poRequest);

             String s= edit.getText().toString();
             if (s.equals("")){
                 // give error message
             }
             else{

                 long lineNr=Long.parseLong(s);

                new BackgroundWorker().execute(lineNr); 
             }

    }


    public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<Long, Void, String[]> {

                     private String METHOD_NAME = "parser" ; 
                 private String NAMESPACE = "http://statusrequest.androidapp.webservice.backend.net";
                 private String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;  
                 private static final String URL = "http://10.35.105.31:8080/SAPInterfaceWebservice/services/XMLTransfromer?wsdl";
                 ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(PurchaseOrderRequest.this);

                    @Override
                    protected String[] doInBackground(Long... lineNr) {
                        String[] failure = new String [1];
                        long lineNumber = lineNr[0];
                        try
                     {
                     SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                     request.addProperty("lineNr", lineNumber); 
                     publishProgress();
                     SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                     envelope.dotNet = true;
                     envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                     HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                     androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
                     Object result = envelope.getResponse();
                     String hString = result.toString();
                     String[] details = hString.split(",");

                     preqnr=details[0].substring(1);
                     return details;
                     } catch (Exception E) {
                     E.printStackTrace();
                     failure[0]="ERROR: "    + E.getClass().getName() + " : " + E.getMessage(); 
                     }
                    return failure; 
                    }      

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {

                         ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.request_detail1)).setText("PO_Number: " +result[0].substring(1));
                         ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.request_detail2)).setText("Result: " +result[1]);
                         ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.request_detail3)).setText("Result: " +result[2]);
                         ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.request_detail4)).setText("Result: " +result[3]);
                         pd.dismiss();    
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {

                        pd.setMessage("Sending...");
                        pd.show();

                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {


                        }

                }
    public static String getPreqnr() {
        return preqnr;
        }

    }
```

So what did I do wrong to cause the app to crash?

If you need any further information, which i missed to point out, please leave a comment and I'll add them.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hey, Just try to put super.onSaveInstanceState(outState); as the first line in onSaveInstanceState. and also in onRestoreInstanceState perform a check like if(savedInstanceState != null){ //do required stuff}

Comment: @Santhosh I had tried this before, the app still crashes. Even so i will use the `if(savedInstanceState != null){ //do required stuff}`part. But as far as I am now, the doesn't even get to the Restore part :( But thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of object is a view with id "R.id.request_detail1" ? In onSaveInstanceState you are casting it to EditText, but in onRestoreInstanceState you are casting it to TextView.

If it is a TextView, then first cast will cause an exception.

Comment: Oh, this made me feel very stupid... Thank you. Now the app doesn't crash anymore. But it still doesn't work...? Any hint for that? (Even if it is out of the scope of the actual question)

Comment: Oh, yeah sure: The request_detail and the poRequest fields are empty, if I get back to the activity. No error occurs. I had information in those fields, when I navigated to the child activity. When I navigate back to this activity, the information are not displayed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what might be the problem. :(

Comment: Np, at least I'm not stuck because of my stupidity anymore :D So now I can search for a real problem